# Application of string function

Tags: c#

what should I  change in this, I know how to count all the vowels but not individually. Would like to state how many 'a', 'e', and etc. are there...thanks

```
 string name;
 var vowels = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
 int  vow= 0;

 Console.Write("Input characters:");
 name= Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

 for (int k=0; k < name.Length; k++)
 {
      if (vowels.Contains(name[k]))
      {
           vow++;
      }
 }

 Console.WriteLine("No. of vowels(s): {0}", vow);


 Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
 Console.ReadKey(true);


 Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You can try using a dictionary, where the keys are the vowels and the values are the number of times that vowel has appeared.

Comment: Why are you including space `' '` as a vowel?

Comment: I don;t understand why most of the answer are proposing use of `Dictionary`. If you look at OP's question, OP is just printing vowel after the count. Here we can optimize code by printing the count inside foreach loop. If someone helps me to understand use of Dictionary then it will be really helpful. FYI @KleberPF, @JoelCoehoorn

Answer (score 2):

```
var vowels = new Dictionary<char, int> () {
    {'a', 0}, {'e', 0}, {'i', 0}, {'o', 0}, {'u', 0}
};
Console.Write("Input characters:");
foreach (char c in Console.ReadLine().ToLower())
{
    if (vowels.ContainsKey(c)) vowels[c]++;
}
```

Comment: I don;t understand why most of the answer are proposing use of Dictionary. If you look at OP's question, OP is just printing vowel after the count. Here we can optimize code by printing the count inside foreach loop. If someone helps me to understand use of Dictionary then it will be really helpful. FYI @KleberPF . (Repeating same comment to get your attention)

Comment: You don't know the count for each vowel until after you get to the end of the loop, so we need somewhere to store the count of each vowel until then. The dictionary is a convenient place to store that information, though an array or separate variables could also work. We could also do it like with your answer, but that would also mean looping through the input a separate time for each vowel. Since the input it likely to be much longer than just the five vowels, that's going to be less efficient.

Comment: Yeah, if the input string length is large, then you code is efficient than mine but if you look at @Jawad's answer, he/she is using `Count()` as well as dictionary. I got confused over there, any way your answer is better than me in terms of performance, +1

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `Dictionary` of vowels, and every time you encounter a vowel increment a number associated with that value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-6.0) from `System.Linq` to count number of vowels in a  string

> Returns the number of elements in a sequence.

```
using System.Linq;
...
//Do you consider space as a vowel?
var vowels = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', ' ' };
Console.Write("Input characters:");
var name= Console.ReadLine().ToLower().ToCharArray(); //Convert name to character array.
foreach(var vowel in vowels)  //iterate over each vowel
{
     var count = name.Count(x => x == vowel);  //Count in entire name array.
     Console.WriteLine($"Count of {vowel} = {count}");
}
```

---

If you want to use count of each vowel after `foreach` loop, then store it in the `Dictionary<char, int>`, otherwise `Dictionary<char, int>` is not required. You can just print vowel and it's count inside `foreach` loop

---

[Try online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bF94c6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dictionary that keeps track of vowels and how many times they occured. Using `Count` from LINQ, you can get the numbers for each occurences.

```
var vowels = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', ' ' };
Dictionary<char, int> count = new Dictionary<char, int>();

Console.Write("input: ");
string name = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
foreach(char vowel in vowels)
{
    count.Add(vowel, name.Count(x => x.Equals(vowel)));
}

foreach(var kvp in count)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"vowel: {kvp.Key} ... occurences: {kvp.Value}");
}

// Prints
input: This is a line contianing most vowels
vowel: a ... occurences: 2
vowel: e ... occurences: 2
vowel: i ... occurences: 5
vowel: o ... occurences: 3
vowel: u ... occurences: 0
vowel:   ... occurences: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion using `Dictionary`, but only storing the vowel `Key`s that are actually found in `name`:

```
var vowels = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

Console.Write("Input characters: ");
var name = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

// Count the occurrence of any vowel in vowels that is present in name
var vowelAndCount = name
    .Where(ch => vowels.Contains(ch))
    .GroupBy(vowel => vowel)
    .ToDictionary(vowel => vowel.Key, vowel => vowel.Count());

foreach (var vowel in vowels)
{
    // If vowel was found in the previous operation, output the vowel count; otherwise, output 0
    Console.WriteLine($"No. of '{vowel}'s: {(vowelAndCount.ContainsKey(vowel) ? vowelAndCount[vowel] : 0)}");
}
```